# arch linux systemd RTC clock script does not execute

Tags: bash, arch-linux, systemd

I have `rtc.service` service in `/etc/systemd/system`:

```
[Unit]
Description=RTC Service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/scripts/script_rtc.sh
```

But the `script_rtc.sh` exists and is executable:

```
[user@comp001 scripts]# ls -asl script_rtc.sh
4 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 79 Jan  1 01:04 script_rtc.sh
[user@comp001 scripts]#
```

Here is script `/scripts/script_rtc.sh`, which only enabled Real Time Clock via i2c:

```
[user@comp001 scripts]# cat script_rtc.sh
#!/bin/sh

sudo echo "ds1307 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device"
[user@comp001 scripts]#
```

Here is also `systemclt -u rtc.service` output:

```
Jan 01 01:00:10 comp001 systemd[1]: Starting RTC Service...
Jan 01 01:00:12 comp001 systemd[1]: rtc.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jan 01 01:00:12 comp001 systemd[1]: Failed to start RTC Service.
Jan 01 01:00:12 comp001 systemd[1]: Unit rtc.service entered failed state.
Jan 01 01:00:12 comp001 systemd[1]: rtc.service failed.
```

Ok, I've modified the script itself for test echo:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "ds1307 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device"
```

Now, I can control it via `systemctl`, but if I do:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "ds1307 0x68" > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device

I get error:
[root@comp001 scripts]# ./script_rtc.sh 
./script_rtc.sh: line 3: echo: write error: Invalid argument
[root@comp001 scripts]#
```

Why??

Comment: If the script is owned by root and triggered as a systemd service, why does it invoke `sudo`? Also, your quotes in the script mean it just echoes the string; it doesn't redirect anything...

Comment: @jasonwryan, good point, but I even cannot get echoing.

Comment: The `Invalid argument` error is out of scope of this (initial) question. It is something to deal with the kernel or the driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way or another, the script cannot be executed.

- Try to launch it from the shell
- Check `noexec`, SELinux, etc (whatever security restrictions you could have)
- Check the shebang in the first line of the script (spaces before #, spaces before !, verify existence of `/bin/sh`)

By the way:

- Remove `sudo` from the script, it is already ran as root
- The redirection should not be enquoted, i. e. `echo "foo" > file`, not `echo "foo > file"`

### HOWEVER

There is no guarantee that your script will get executed *after* `i2c-1` is initialized, so you have **a race condition** here. You'd better use udev rule instead of a script altogether:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="i2c", ATTR{name}=="<contents of file /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/name>", ATTR{new_device}="ds1307 0x68"
```

Place that line in `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-i2c-rtc.rules`.

Answer (score -1):

The echo should be:

```
echo "ds1307 0x68">/sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device
```

There are no spaces..... and this works for me. 
Eon't forget to:

```
systemctl enable <your.service>...
```